# Unable to exit shell script when using exec command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, error-handling, sh

I have one main script(deploy_test.sh) which loops through files using find command and executes several other shell scripts. The main script does not exit even if other shell encounters failure. I used several options at the start of script but still iam unable to exit and script is continuing till the end.

deploy_test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail
shopt -s execfail
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"


echo "Do you want to Continue: [Yes/No]"

read action

if [ $action = "Yes" ]
then


 echo "Executing scripts"
 find ${SCRIPT_DIR}/folder2 -type f -name '*.sh' -exec bash {} \;
 echo $?
 echo "This should also not be printed"


else
echo "nothing"
exit 1
fi
```

My folder2 has 2 .sh files (1.sh and 2.sh)

1.sh(have some special character at the end of script)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -eu

echo "hi iam in 1.sh and i have error in this file"
`
```

2.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -eu

echo "hi iam in 2.sh and i have no error in this file"
```

Ouptut when i execute script

```
(deploy) CSI-0048:test_test smullangi$ ./deploy_test.sh
Do you want to Continue: [Yes/No]
Yes
Executing scripts
hi iam in 1.sh and i have error in this file
/Users/smullangi/Desktop/test_test/folder2/1.sh: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/Users/smullangi/Desktop/test_test/folder2/1.sh: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
hi iam in 2.sh and i have no error in this file
0
This should also not be printed
```

I expected this script to exit after encountering error in 1.sh file which had special character. But whatever options I tried the script is not exiting after it encounters error.

Any help is really appreciated. I am executing this on macbook (macos catalina v10.15.3) with bash version(3.2.57(1)-release)

**#UPDATE1:**

Also i feel script is not executing at all. If there are no errors in the script then also it exits. In short i feel my scripts in folder1/folder2 is not getting executed after modyfing code as per Phillippe suggestions

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail
shopt -s execfail
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"


echo "Do you want to Continue: [Yes/No]"

read action

if [ $action = "Yes" ]
then


 echo "Executing scripts"
 find ${SCRIPT_DIR}/folder2 -type f -name '*.sh' -exec false bash {} +
 #find ${SCRIPT_DIR}/folder2 -type f -name '*.sh' -exec bash {} \;
 echo $?
 echo "This should also not be printed"


else
echo "nothing"
exit 1
fi
```

Output

```
(deploy) CSI-0048:test_test smullangi$ ./deploy_test.sh 
Do you want to Continue: [Yes/No]
Yes
Executing scripts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any elegant solution using exec. So i used xargs in find command and it is working perfectly fine. Shell exits with appropriate error message. I used this as my reference https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571215/force-xargs-to-stop-on-first-command-error

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail
shopt -s execfail

SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"


echo "Do you want to Continue: [Yes/No]"

read action

if [ $action = "Yes" ]
then


 echo "Executing scripts"
 find ${SCRIPT_DIR}/folder2 -type f -name '*.sh' | xargs -I {} sh -c 'bash "$1" || exit 255' sh {}
 echo $?
 echo "This should also not be printed"


else
echo "nothing"
exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` does not always exit with error code when commands it runs give error:

```
find ${SCRIPT_DIR}/folder1 -type f -exec false {} \;
```

Above `find` command itself runs successfully even though every command it runs gives error.

Following `find` gives error:

```
find ${SCRIPT_DIR}/folder1 -type f -exec false {} +
```

To have error handling of each script, you can do

```
cd ${SCRIPT_DIR}/folder1
for script in ./*.sh; do
    $script
done
```

Comment: Hi Philippe. Thanks for the answer. It is working partially. The script is exiting now but it does not throw any error. How to show error on command line and then exit?

Comment: If it's exiting now, you may need to paste new version of script and output.

Comment: I have put code block and output as per your suggestion in the question itself

Comment: `-exec false bash {} +` DOES exit with error, as said in my answer.

Comment: It did not throw me error. I have run this script with 50 files inside. None of them have error but it did not give me any output. It is exiting in a second

Comment: I saw this post which is similar to mine. But not sure how to replace function. I dont have problem changing my solution to xargs as long as it works. can you please help. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566834/xargs-does-not-quit-on-error/566837